# How can I call method from data on vue.js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuex

My vue component like this :

```vue
<template>
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs nav-tabs-bg">
    <li v-for="tab in tabs" role="presentation" :class="setActive(tab.url)">
      <a :href="baseUrl + tab.url">{{tab.title}}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>      
</template>
    
<script>
  export default {
    props: ['shop'],
    data() {
      return{
        tabs: [
          {
            title: 'product',
            url: '/store/' + this.shop.id + '/' + strSlug(this.shop.name)
          },
          {
            title: 'info',
            url: '/store/' + this.shop.id + '/' + strSlug(this.shop.name) + '/info'
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    methods: {
      setActive(pathname){
        return {active: window.location.pathname == pathname}
      },
      strSlug: function(val) {
        return _.kebabCase(val)
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

If the code run, there exist error like this :

> [Vue warn]: Error in data(): "ReferenceError: strSlug is not defined"

If I console.log(window.location.pathname), the result like this :

> /store/21/chelsea-hazard-store

So if it is the same as url with data in tabs, then it will active

I call the strSlug method to convert each into lowercase and convert spaces into `-`

Seems it can not call the method from the data

How can I solve the error?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

When accessing data or methods from within the vue object, use `this.thing`. In your case, that would be `this.strSlug(this.shop.name)`.

Answer (score 26):

If you have a function in `data` that will be used in a context of another object (like an event handler, for example), then `this` will not point to the Vue instance. You will have to preserve the reference in another variable from the scope of `data()`:

```
methods: {
    shuffle() {}
},
data() {
    var self = this;
    return {
        onClick: function() {
            self.shuffle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was looking for this to implement i18n (translation) in vuetify validation. It worked like a charm.  I was driving me crazy. Thank You! .... based on your example i did self.$t('message') and it worked.

Comment: Vue calls data() once when creating data. After that, Vue manages the return value of data() with the $data property.

Therefore, there is no need to replace this with self in data() since data() is never called from an event handler, etc.

As The Guy with The Hat answered, just append this to strSlug.

Similarly, there is no need to replace this with self in the definition of methods.

Answer (score 11):

Does not work even with 'this.' because that function has not been defined at the time data is being initialized. I think you have to do it in the created() life-cycle hook.