# CKEditor5-Vue autosave problem. I can't call instance in autosave function

Tags: vue.js, ckeditor5

The editor work fine except autosave.

I import autosave plugin properly,and I can receive the return data.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cDW9x.jpg
in this case, i can receive the autosave data.

But I can't call Vue instance inside the autosave function.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Nyq4.jpg

https://i.stack.imgur.com/sevjo.jpg

I can't call my vue instance by 'this',that means i can't use methods,vuex store...and so on.

How can i fix hti?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a bit late but for anyone (like myself) looking for an answer to this I followed the advice in this [SO link][1]

```
data() {
   var self = this
   ...
   return {
     editorConfig: {
       autosave: {
         waitingTime: 3000, // in ms               
         save(editor) {
           self.saveData(editor.getData())
         }
       },
      }
    }

   }


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/a/61509032/558720
```

Comment: I already added the method saveData, but I got the error: `Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: self.saveData is not a function.` Any recommendation?